# Change classname of div

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

In my page I want to change the class name of the div whose id is answer1 in div id=question. How can I do that? Thanks.

```
$('question1 answer1').addClassName('new_name');

<div id="question1">
   <div id="answer1" class="old_name">
   </div>
</div>

<div id="question2">
   <div id="answer2" class="old_name">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it has been pointed out, any selector method requires an iterator of some sort, so you can not just apply a method to all objects returned.  You will notice in the documentation for `Element.select` that this is supposed to alleviate having to explicitly convert the object to an array, but I have not had luck with this on jsfiddle. However, I did try the following:

```
 $('answer2').addClassName('new_name');
```

​
And it worked just fine.  I don't know if the issue is that you are trying to traverse the DOM in your original element object (by using question1 answer1) and this requires the object/array iterator, or if it's just a hiccup elsewhere in the code. But in your specific example, since you know the id of the actual element you want to change the class of, the above code should work fine without specificing the parent element or using an array index of any kind.

I will admit that prototypejs threw me off because they use the same method names for the Element objects as Enumerable objects, so I saw the first instance of `select` and thought it looked pretty straight forward.  Having now seen that almost every class/method requires you to set up a selector and convert it or manually traverse it, I will definitly say that this would be *much* easier with jquery and that your initial comment that they are almost the same is specifically not true in this scenario. Perhaps protojs offers some features that jquery does not, perhaps your code is tied to protojs (I worked on a project for a year that had to use YUI, which is a much bigger nightmare, trust me), but jquery is set up to play nice with prototypejs, so in cases like these, I'd consider using both. In jquery, the code would have been:

```
jQuery.noConflict();  // Avoids $ fight between jquery and prototypejs
jQuery( '#question1 #answer1' ).addClass('new_name');
```

or, to remove the old one first:

```
jQuery.noConflict();  // Avoids $ fight between jquery and prototypejs
jQuery( '#question1 #answer1' )removeClass('old_name').addClass('new_name');
```

Also, prototype has a toggleClass method that is probably also unnecessarilly esoteric, but maybe you should read up on:   [toggleClassName](http://prototypejs.org/api/element/toggleClassName)

And I wouldn't be this pissy about wasting my time on this (because I don't like to consider getting stuck learning a new framework a waste of time) except that their documentation, while attractive, has the worst examples I've ever seen. They all assume you have some fundamental idea without ever a friendly real world example or hyperlink to the difference between an instance and a class, and their examples distinguishing the two are **identical**.  I'm definitely going to take some time out later today to find the real best answer to your question, out of spite and pride, if nothing else, but if it really comes down to having to iterator *every* time, just use vanilla js and use this framework when it's actually useful.

Comment: PS: This would be much easier with jquery, so unless you are married to prototypejs, I'd make the switch.

Comment: Much easier? There's practically no difference between the two libraries in how something like this is accomplished.

Comment: Your answer seems to be using a mix between Protoype and jQuery. You'll need to access the individual element(s) in the returned $$ array before calling element methods. Prototype doesn't automatically apply those calls. Either use Array.each or directly access the elements with []

Comment: I've never used prototype but I copied all sample code from their api page. didn't see a need for each or array specificity when using addclass method (which does exist in jquery as well, fyi). Will double check and edit if I misread.

Comment: Good thing you're answering a prototype specific question and advocating against the library having never used it. Oh snap!

Comment: Good thing people are willing to read the documentation and offer free advice that a consultant would charge $50-$150/hr and probably start off with the same steps (reading the manual).  Not to mention the crime of 1) taking the time to learn about an unfamiliar library and 2) knowing exactly what you are talking about when you point out my heinous oversight because it's a common js framework issue, not exclusive to prototypejs. If I had known those who used it were so touchy, I would have skipped over it. Next time I'll know.

Comment: PS - I admitted I made a mistake right away, you two are the ones that are acting like jquery is the bastard framework and protojs is the holy grail.   Read my edit for the right answer.  Coming right up.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came off as a jag - I just get frustrated with the frequent comment on SO of "don't use prototype, use jQuery, it's better/easier/has more support/etc." since that's not a helpful answer.

Comment: I'm not trying to pick a fight or anything, but I've expanded on my answer to try to clear up your questions in your first paragraph. HTH

Comment: I'm not really mad at you, just taking it out on whoever says oh snap. sorry. And thank for the expanded answer. I do try to answer questions outside of my comfort zone to force myself to learn, so all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `$('answer1')` will get you a reference to the div element that you want. The `$` function returns an element with the given id string (or null if none was found). Note that you don't use a selector string when using `$` - it only operates on ids.

The `$$` function takes in a CSS selector string and returns an array of all matching elements, or an empty array if nothing matched. If you wanted or needed to go that route, you could locate the same div like this:

```
$$('#question1 .answer1')[0]
```

Once you have your element reference using either of the above methods, you can use `addClassName` or `removeClassName` or any other element methods available.